# How do I download files whose path is stored in sql database android?

Tags: android, sql, jtds

After long research, I learnt that storing files direct to sql databases is not the best option, its better to put the files in a directory and save the path in database. Am stuck, here searched everywhere, after storing the path, how do I now get to the file and download it in android.
Am using android and have connected to the sql servers with jtds. The specific file i want to download is an apk file. Anyone to start me off?

Diagram below explains my scenario, hope someone gets it and helps:
[Scenario photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXOJV.png)

Comment: If the file is already in a directory on your Android device then there is no need to download the file.

Comment: Not on the phone device, but on the server machine. I want to pull it to phone so that i can install.

Comment: You got the opportunity to tell someting more about your server but as you did not we still cannot advise anything. And better edit your post then adding comments.

Comment: Already done, check out the diagram I just attached, hope it helps you get what am in.

Comment: And what is the problem asking jtds to download the file? I have no idea what api you could use with jtds.